# php mysql and mobile clients, displaying dates from UTC to different timezones

Tags: php, android, ios, mysql, timezone

I have a RESTful PHP Backend with MySQL, which serves android and ios clients, we have users from different timezones, the dates in database are in UTC.

In order to show these dates in users current timezone, I have spent some days researching, and talking with the mobile developers, finally came up with this proposal:

1) When Android or iOS device starts, it sends the current device time to server, upon which server calculates the offset between two times and returns back to client, for example -03:30

2) Client stores that response (-03:30), and sends it in a header field with each request it is performing to the backend.

3) When PHP wants to SELECT a date, it gets that request header value, validates it and uses that value as following

```
"SELECT CONVERT_TZ(field,'+00:00','-03:30')"
```

Is that the gist of what has to be done? Am I missing a better solution?

I would like to know your opinion in above 3 steps, specially first step, since on the first place I thought mobile developers can perform this calculation based on server timestamp, but was refused.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Since the client knows the timezone, the better solution is for the API to send UTC dates and have the client convert it to the desired timezone. I'm not sure why your mobile developers would refuse to do this; this is how it's commonly done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store all dates in UTC(GMT+0) in the database, and then retrieve them as such from the database into the client (phone device).

Then have each device apply the offset upon receiving the timestamp. Potential example:

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
Date databaseUTCTime = getFromDB();
int offsetFromUtc = tz.getOffset(databaseUTCTime.getTime()) / 1000;
```

If you want to share user's time including their timezone, perhaps also store the timestamp which is not UTC and converting it without an offset?

```
$t = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $raw_stored_time);
```